# Email not sent from within catch or finally when exception is rethrown. Why?

Tags: apex, exception

As I am otherwise [unable to debug a long running batch process in a customer org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/tracking-errors-in-batch-impossible-as-dev-console-stops-logging-or-breaks-with) (logs are lost when I am not logged in all the time via subscriber support) of our managed ISV package, I tried to send the exception via email.

The code looks like this:

```
try {
   Integer a =  3/ 0;
}
catch(Exception e) {
    notifyDevelopersOf(e, 'MyClass');
    throw e; // Email is only sent when this line is commented out!
}
```

...

```
public static void notifyDevelopersOf(Exception e, String locationName) {
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String orgName = UserInfo.getOrganizationName();
    String user = UserInfo.getUserName();
    String message = e.getMessage();
    String stacktrace = e.getStackTraceString();
    String exType = '' + e.getTypeName();
    String line = '' + e.getLineNumber();
    String theTime = '' + System.now();

    String subject = String.format('Exception thrown at {0} by user {1} in org {2} (Id: {3})', new List<String>{ locationName, user, orgName, orgId });
    String body = String.format('Time: {0}\nMessage: {1}\nStacktrace: {2}\nLine: {3}', new List<String>{ theTime, message, stacktrace, line });

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'developers@acme.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(body);

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

The **email is only sent out when I DO NOT rethrow the exception** in the catch. It even does not work when I send and rethrow in a finally clause.

I need to rethrow the exception because I want the batch to fail and have error messages in the common places as well.

**EDIT: Even making the method that sends the email `@future` or calling it from `finally` doesn't work.**

Comment: Can you share the code of `notifyDevelopersOf()`? (just so I can try to reproduce the problem?)

Comment: this topic is also covered at length here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54931/how-can-i-cause-side-effects-outside-a-transaction-context with other ideas on solving

Answer (score 8):

As per the documentation of [Outbound Email](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound.htm):

> The email is not sent until the Apex transaction is committed.

An unhandled exception will cause the Apex transaction to roll back, cancelling the e-mail.
A solution for you would be to mark the `notifyDevelopersOf()` function with `@future`. This will create a new request and transaction for the execution function. Note that you cannot make more than 10 calls to a future method per request.

**EDIT**; After some fiddling about I've found out that future methods won't be executed too if the transaction fails. So using future methods will not help you. As far as I can tell, there is really no way to get around the fact that e-mails will not be sent if the transaction isn't commit. Is there any way you can make it work without rethrowing the exception? Maybe using `addError()`, or, if you are using VF `ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);` I'm not 100% sure that will work, but it could be worth trying.

**Another edit**; You can make an HTTP callout from the catch that will not be cancelled if the exception is rethrown, something like this:

```
try {
    Integer a = 3/0;
} catch(Exception e){
    //set the url
    String url = 'http://www.mydomain.net/SendEmail?param1=value1';
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

    throw e;
}
```

A major drawback of this solution is that the client needs to add your domain name in the list of trusted remote site in their environment.

Comment: As I am passing a non primitive type I made the email sending future but not the creation of the message strings. And it did not work even with future...

Comment: I also change the code so the notifgication is done in a finally clause. Should the finally be called in any cases EVEN if the transaction is commited?!

Comment: Finally will always be executed. I'm gonna try it with a future method.

Comment: Hm, it seems that the context of future methods is not as seperate as I thought.

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer... Couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: +1 that ANY changes that can be rolled back will be. The only way I can see if getting information out of the system in the case of an unhandled exception is a HTTP callout (which won't work from triggers)

Comment: Sounds like design bug @ca_peterson

Comment: I'd argue it's actually a quite useful feature - the same behavior is exhibited by Database.rollback, which can be incredibly powerful with this in mind. Still, I wish there was an annotation or something like it to allow persisting a block in the event of an unhandled exception.

Comment: I've tried making an HTTP callout from the future function, that didn't work as well. Making an HTTP callout directly from the catch, right above the throw does work. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

When an exception is thrown, none of the work you did during that `try{}` block is kept, which includes sending an email.

One way to get around this is to use custom Exceptions and different catch() blocks on your main try/catch to handle different exceptions differently:

```
    class ContactUpdateException extends Exception {}
    class OpportunityUpdateException extends Exception {}

    public PageReference tryExample()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            try
            {
                update listOfContacts;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ContactUpdateException('Contact Update Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            }

            try
            {
                update listOfOpportunities;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new OpportunityUpdateException('Opportunity Update Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        catch (ContactUpdateException e)
        {
            //send email or do whatever for this kind of exception
        }
        catch (OpportunityUpdateException e)
        {
            //send email or do whatever for this kind of exception
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle all other kinds of exceptions
        }
    }
```

Comment: My question was never about work in a try but in a catch or finally and those were solely made for that purpose.

Comment: I am suggesting that you wrap that catch inside an outer try/catch, so that you can handle your exceptions within your code. This will allow you to complete your processing. The point is that everything within a transaction in which an unhandled exception appears is discarded. The only way to preserve information like that is through the exception itself, as in my code above.

Answer (score 2):

If your DML is working and you get an exception on something else (null pointer) then

1. you could set a Savepoint at the start of each execute(),
2. wrap the entire execute code block with a try-catch
3. in the catch, send the email, set a global variable to 'failed' and then do a rollback
4. Use global variables in the class to communicate status between each execute invocation
5. In your finish(), examine the global variables and output a batch status message to your favorite place (email, special SObject, ...)

Comment: Is finish always called? Even when errors occur or jobs get auto aborted?

Comment: good question, i don't know -- you could try an easy experiment in your execute() by doing something that try{} catch{} won't catch - like exceeding a limit (e.g do a for loop of 200,000 statements).  This would let you see if finish() is called.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this wrapping approach does not work if you are using `addError()` to tell the user about something.  The `addError()` or `setMessage()` still leaves the transaction uncommitted, even if you've put that in the wrapped area, so the email message won't go out.

Comment: This looks more like a comment, but with only a rep of 1 you couldn't post it there. We will move it - meanwhile - go get some points :)  Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Modified it so it wasn't just a comment, added info from subsequent experiments.