# Unable to make web callout even after Database.rollback

Tags: apex, callout

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
insert new Campaign(Name='test');
Database.rollback(sp);

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://google.com');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = 
    http.send(req);
system.debug(req);
```

If you paste the above code into an anonymous block and execute, you will get the following error message:

> System.CalloutException: You ahve uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

However, as you can see, I *am* rolling back on the third line there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

You're not able to do that, you can't do an HTTP callout either after a DML operation or a setting of a Savepoint. [Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm) here mentions DML, but not the Savepoint that I can see, but that is the case.

Comment: Using SavePoint *does* cost a DML operation, however (of the 150/transaction variety). [Transaction Control](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm) explains this: "Each savepoint you set counts against the governor limit for DML statements."

Comment: The error message says "Please commit or rollback before calling out." How, then, am I supposed to rollback to do my callout?

Comment: Why are you rolling back anyway, what would be the point of that? I think in light of what limitations there are around this, you'll need to refactor your code. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm rolling back because of an error condition in a future method, which is invoked by a REST service I've exposed. Client has an endpoint that I can hit with an error message, so the intention is to roll back and then call out to notify of the error.

Comment: Yeah thats going to be tricky without some refactoring. Here's an interesting post that has some creative solutions http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54931/how-can-i-cause-side-effects-outside-a-transaction-context

Answer (score 2):

In Spring `24 we added the ability in Apex to explicitly release a savepoint. After release the callout will be permitted. See [Make Callouts After Rolling Back DML and Releasing Savepoints](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_SavepointCallouts.htm&release=248&type=5)

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try {
    // Try a database operation
    insert new Account(name='Foo');
    integer bang = 1 / 0;

} catch (Exception ex) {

    Database.rollback(sp);
    // Also releases any savepoints created after 'sp'
    Database.releaseSavepoint(sp); 

    // Callout is allowed because uncommitted work is rolled back and savepoints are released
    makeACallout(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Apex Governer limits Database.savepoint() is mentioned as a DML operation. Hence we can't make a callout after that.